# Why is my multiple-select with selected not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I am trying to use a multiple-selection drop-down but I am unable to figure out why it is not working.

```
<%= select( map1[:field_name], "id", map1[:field_codes], :multiple => "true", :selected => optionVal[value] )%>
```

It does not give me any error, and adding `multiple => true` does not make any difference.

Comment: When you say it's "not working" you mean it works, but you can't select multiple items?  Have you tried CTRL then click?

Comment: It renders it as simple dropdown not something as list where we can select multiple options. CTRL does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple is html_options and selected is helper option. Select has next syntax 
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})

So, write

```
<%= select( map1[:field_name], "id", map1[:field_codes], { :selected => optionVal[value] }, { :multiple => "true" } )%>
```

[Read more about select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

Comment: Thanks, It really helped me. Also it cleared the Syntax of Select :)